# How do I link created pages on site.com?

Tags: site.com, url

I have a Cases and a Documentation page which displays the case and article records (data repeaters). I have created two pages "case detail" and "article detail" which should display the case/article record I click on. How do I link those pages. I am unable to find the URLs of Case detail and Article detail pages so that I can link using URLs from the Cases and the Documentation pages.

Answer (score 3):

I found the documentation for Linking pages which solved my issue:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_communities_url.htm&language=en_US
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_siteforce/wb_siteforce.pdf